# firebase functions says "Functions did not deploy properly."

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I want to use Stripe with Firebase Functions.

Attempting to deploy the following source code to functions will result in an error.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
// This is your real test secret API key.
const stripe = require("stripe")("STRIPE KEY HERE");

app.use(express.static("."));
app.use(express.json());

const calculateOrderAmount = items => {
  // Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
  // Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
  // people from directly manipulating the amount on the client
  return 1400;
};

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body;
  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "usd"
  });

  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
  });
});

module.exports.express = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is what I want to achieve.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder

I want to deploy to Firebase Functions using react for the front and Node for the back end.

＜/functions/package.json＞

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

When I tried the command `"firebase deploy --only" functions: express "`, I got the following error:

> Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Function cannot be initialized

This was accompanied by this Log object:

```json
{
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
        "code": 3,
        "message": "Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": "MYADDRESS@gmail.com"
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "resourceName": "projects/MYPROJECT/locations/us-central1/functions/express"
}
```

```
i deploying functions
i functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled ...
i functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled ...
✔ functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔ functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i functions: preparing functions directory for uploading ...
i functions: packaged functions (44.09 KB) for uploading
✔ functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i functions: creating Node.js 12 function express (us-central1) ...

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
         express (us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
     firebase deploy --only "functions: express"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
     firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Is there error output in the logs in Firebase Console?

Comment: Please include the dependencies section of your `package.json` file in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the Express.js app as an HTTPS function with

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

instead of doing

```
module.exports.express = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

---

Then you need to deploy with, for example, `firebase deploy --only functions`.

Note that it seems that there is an extra double quote (`"`) in the command you entered:

> I typed the command "firebase deploy --only" functions: express "

Comment: All this does is change the export from "express" to "app"?

Comment: @samthecodingman Not quite, what I believe My Tarnec is referring to specifically is the `module.` prefix, the name itslef isn't what matters but I believe that when processing it can lead to confusion. It shouldn't, but still. Also, on the note of this answer: @dksq , did you include the quote in your command or not?